# Google Analytics API on PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

But still I got this issue:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message '(get) missing required param: 'ids'' in /home/sample/www/test/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Resource.php:163 Stack trace: #0 /home/sample/www/test/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Analytics.php(2107): Google_Service_Resource->call('get', Array, 'Google_Service_...') #1 /home/sample/www/test/google-api-php-client-master/practicein.php(57): Google_Service_Analytics_DataRealtime_Resource->get('ga:********', 'ga:pageviews', '2015-03-07', '2015-04-04') #2 /home/sample/www/test/index.php(34): require_once('/home/lanforest...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/sample/www/test/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Resource.php on line 163

And I think the codes around here is wrong.

```
$results = $analytics->data_realtime->get(
    $analytics_view_id,
    'ga:pageviews',//**I did correct this.**
    '2015-03-07',
    '2015-04-04'
);

//**I think these goes wrong**
$totals = $results->getTotalsForAllResults();
$array = array("activeUsers" => $totals["rt:activeUsers"]);
```

I want to see just page views. What can I code?

I think I got active user value.But,It still warning.
What kind of error is this?

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sample/www/test/index.php:16) in /home/sample/www/test/google-api-php-client-master/practicein.php on line 76

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sample/www/test/index.php:16) in /home/sample/www/test/google-api-php-client-master/practicein.php on line 77

{"activeUsers":"0"}//this is the result.
```

Comment: Can you share with us your code?

Comment: Since you're just including practicein.php, that it's the code we need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your starcktrace i see:

```
#1 .../practicein.php(66): Google_Service_Analytics_DataRealtime_Resource->get('ga:*******', '2015-03-07', '2015-04-04', 'ga:pageviews'
```

You are calling the `get` method with wrong params: first one is your ga id, the second one must be metrics, then you can pass opt params.

Check the `get` method docs in `src/Google/Service/Analytics.php`:

```
/**
 * Returns real time data for a view (profile). (realtime.get)
 *
 * @param string $ids Unique table ID for retrieving real time data. Table ID is
 * of the form ga:XXXX, where XXXX is the Analytics view (profile) ID.
 * @param string $metrics A comma-separated list of real time metrics. E.g.,
 * 'rt:activeUsers'. At least one metric must be specified.
 * @param array $optParams Optional parameters.
 *
 * @opt_param int max-results The maximum number of entries to include in this
 * feed.
 * @opt_param string sort A comma-separated list of dimensions or metrics that
 * determine the sort order for real time data.
 * @opt_param string dimensions A comma-separated list of real time dimensions.
 * E.g., 'rt:medium,rt:city'.
 * @opt_param string filters A comma-separated list of dimension or metric
 * filters to be applied to real time data.
 * @return Google_Service_Analytics_RealtimeData
 */
 public function get($ids, $metrics, $optParams = array())
```

Comment: `try {
        $results=$analytics->data_realtime->get(
            $analytics_view_id,//viewID
            'ga:pageviews',//主要指標(metrics)
            '2015-03-07',//開始日
            '2015-04-04'//終了日
        );
        print_r($results['rows']);`

Comment: @ForestTatsuya Glad to know, if everything is ok, please accept the answer ^^